# asp.net page not work without parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

When I call a page localhost:29773/folder/simple.aspx without parameter, I get a redirect to the index.html. 
But when I call this: localhost:29773/folder/simple.aspx? (with ? ) it works. 
(there is no redirect to the index page in the code)

Do you have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Check your global.asax, your web.config and any other redirect module that you have add some redirect/rewrite commands.

Comment: you mean no redirects on the `simple.aspx` page and not the index page

Comment: I mean that you have somewhere a global redirect / rewrite that capture it and change it

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. That was because the firefox do cache for the redirects.

Comment: show an SSCCE (http://SSCCE.org)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the solution. That was because the firefox works cache for the redirects.